# Web & Mobile analytics Track Purchase Details with AJAX Redirector Call

Tags: marketing-cloud, ajax, web, tracking-extract

I want to use use ajax call to track purchase items. I found [this documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/track_conversion/) but it's not very clear in particular how compose the url to pass to the function.

Comment: I bet it is clearer than your question ;) - Please review [Ask] and provide some more details.